# Elasticsearch in a custom VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, aws-elasticsearch

I'm new to the AWS-VPC I've created some AWS-Lambda functions, which access AWS-Elasticsearch. now I want to Place the Elasticsearch inside a VPC. What are the best methods to do that? Should I need to create a new VPC or use the default VPC and then create a private subnet?

Lambda functions that I've created also access several other AWS resources(SQS, SNS, Cognito, etc.). So How do I configure Elasticsearch? Also For creating a subnet we choose a set of IP addresses (CIDR). How do I know the amount of IP addresses I've to choose. What does that actually mean?

I've read about [VPC to VPC NAT](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/), What are the steps I should take care of? How do I configure Lambda and Elasticsearch?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

There are so many small questions in this, for VPC/Subnets/CIDR, you can quickly use and test based on the default VPC. For further VPC/Subnets/CIDR customization, you better go through some guides or some learning courses.

For Lambda access to ES domains, you need to ensure:

- Lambda is required to be placed under a VPC.
- ES domain is required to be placed under a VPC.
- Allow ES domain access with Lambda security group.

This is for network connection prerequisites, for ES domain requests, you better check your ES domain setup and Lambda code.

Comment: What are your thoughts on creating a private subnet inside the default VPC, and place elasticsearch there? I'm using environment credentials to access elasticsearch from my code.

Comment: Then ensure NAT Gateway is there with your private subnets: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/